# Message Sent to Deallocated Instance iOS [_UILayoutGuide isDescendantOfView:]:

Tags: ios

Trying to find the source of this EXC_BAD_ACCESS in my iOS App. I get the following on the console:

[_UILayoutGuide isDescendantOfView:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fd14037d0e0

And have used Zombies to try to track this down:

[image: Screenshot from Zombies]

I can't find the source of the problem. Double clicking on any of the stack traces in Zombies doesn't lead to any of my code.

Hope you can help - before I bang my head too hard off the wall!

-Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found the answer - the problem was a constraint in the Storyboard.

The constraint was not "installed", but I found that by deleting UI elements one by one I could track down the problem constraint. No apparent reason why it would cause a crash like this, but deleting it has fixed the issue.

Comment: i don't know what is wrong with the constraint that when you remove all constraint for that view it will work properly, maybe its because the allocation thingy i really don't know why this answer work.Thanks for this idea

Comment: My issue was solved by changing the ViewController `Build for` target `iOS 10 or later` at `Show File inspector` -> `Interface Builder Document`. which was set to iOS 11 it's causing crash only in iOS 10 devices.